# Java String optimisation

Tags: java, string, substring

How many Strings does this create?

```
String test(String text) {
  return "string 1 " +
    text + " string 2 " +
    "string 3";
}
```

Comment: motivation? is this an interview question or what?

Comment: Which version of Java? I believe the compiler has been optimised over the years which changes the performance of string concatentation, and therefore the answer will differ.

Comment: No it's not homework or an interview question, I came across this at work. But why does it matter? @codemwnci, it's 1.6

Comment: it helps the answerers frame their work, and it helps *YOU* get a better answer when your question is clear and shares context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No new String calls are present here, the only one that exists is in StringBuilder.toString, so

1

```
java.lang.String test(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   Stack=3, Locals=2, Args_size=2
   0:   new #16; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   ldc #18; //String string 1 
   6:   invokespecial   #20; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9:   aload_1
   10:  invokevirtual   #23; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   13:  ldc #27; //String  string 2 
   15:  invokevirtual   #23; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   18:  ldc #29; //String string 3
   20:  invokevirtual   #23; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   23:  invokevirtual   #31; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   26:  areturn
```

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy to answer by compiling the code, then inspecting the bytecode with `javap -c`. In this particular case, the compiler should generate code like

```
String result = new StringBuilder("string1").
    append(text).append("string2").append("string3").toString();
```

so depending on how you look at it, you might say only one, or if you're one of those people who likes to count literals as being "created" when they're used, you could say four.

Comment: and if you look at the compiled code you will see _NO_ new String calls. (Only one that happens is in the StringBuilder.toString())

Answer (score 3):

`javap`is your friend. I put your code into S.java and deassembled it using `javap -c S`:

```
Compiled from "S.java"
public class S extends java.lang.Object{
public S();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public java.lang.String test(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   ldc     #4; //String string 1 
   9:   invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   12:  aload_1
   13:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   16:  ldc     #6; //String  string 2 
   18:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   21:  ldc     #7; //String string 3
   23:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   26:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   29:  areturn

}
```

With OpenJDK 1.6.0_22 there is only one StringBuilder and one String created.

Answer (score -1):

this is the equivalent of

```
 (new StringBuilder((new StringBuilder((new StringBuilder("String 1")).append(text).toString())).append("string 2 ").toString()).append("string 3").toString();
```

that's 3 stringbuilders and 6 strings.  The way to optimize this is:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("string 1");
    sb.append(test);
    sb.append(" string 2 ");
    sb.append("string 3");
    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: i only count 1 string this method 'creates', the other strings are created when the class is loaded, not due to this method.

Comment: this is *completely* untrue. Only one `StringBuilder` is constructed, and `append` is called for each subsequent string. The code you've shown as being "optimized" is actually what the compiler emits. Check it out using `javap -c`.

Comment: @gabuzo: *All* JDKs have *always* done this; they've always been smart enough to use "append" for concatenation on a single line. It's concatenating in multiple statements in a loop that's always been the bugbear.

Comment: @Ernest yes I removed my comment because I just used jad with various -source -target parameters and look at the result with jad. It happens that jad gave different results when in pre 1.5 version using StringBuffer than in 1.5+ version using StringBuilder.